# How to prove "A matrix commutating with all Idempotent matrices is necessarly scalar"

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck to prove this problem, Probably I have done for $2$ order matrices.

MY TRY:
Let $P$ be any idempotent and we are to find $A$ such that $AP=PA$.
We have three precise cases.

CASE $1$: If all the eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$.As $P$ is diagonalizable it has  eigenspace of dimension $2$ and it follows that $P=O$, zero matrix. So any $A$ will commute with $P$.

CASE $2$: If all the eigenvalues of $P$ are $1$, as $P$ is diagonalizable it has two independent vectors  , say $v_1,v_2$ such that $Pv_1 =v_1, Pv_2 =v_2$. Now any vector can be expressed a , say $v$ can be expressed as $v =c_1v_1 +c_2v_2$ $\implies$ $ Pv = c_1Av_1 $ $+c_2Av_2$ $\implies$ $Pv =c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 $ $\implies$ $Pv =v$, for any $v\in R^2$. So $P$ becomes an identity and so any matrix $A$ will commute with $P$.

CASE $3$: Let $0,1$ are the two eigenvalues of $P$. as $P$ is diagonalizable we can write any vector $v \in R^2$ as direct-sum of two vectors $v_1,v_2$ i.e. $v =v_1 +v_2$ with $Pv_1 =v_1, Pv_2 =0$.

Now $AP(v_1) =A(v_1) =c_1v_1 +c_2v_2$ ( I assume $Av_1 =c_1v_1 +c_2v_2, c_1,c_2$ are scalers)

$PA(v_1) = P(c_1v_1 +c_2v_2) =c_1v_1$, Now as $AP =PA$ ,we get $c_2 = 0$, Similarly if I take $Av_2 =d_1v_1 +d_2v_2$ then I find that $d_1 =0$.

Hence $Av_1 =c_1v_1 ;Av_2 =d_2v_2$ and $A$ becomes diagonalizable . Suppose $c_1 \ne d_2$, I'm choosing $$
                            \begin{pmatrix}
                             c_1 & 0 \\
                              0 & d_2
                            \end{pmatrix}
                             $$ as $A$.If I choose $P$ as $$
                                                          \begin{pmatrix}
                                                          1 & 1 \\
                                                          0 & 0
                                                          \end{pmatrix}
                                                          $$ .  $AP \ne PA$.
So I have to take those eigenvalues of $A$ equal such that $A$ commutes with all the idempotent $P$'s Then $v=c_1v_1 + c_2v_2$ $\implies$ $Av = c_1v$ ,(as $c_1 = d_2$). Clearly ,$A$ becomes scalar matrix and I know that scalar matrix commutes with any matrix , it will commute with any Idempotent matrix.

So finally considering all those three cases i'm claiming $A$ is scalar matrix in $M_2(R)$ . But How can I prove it in $n$ ordered matrices.please preovide me any hint. Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Jos`e Carlos Santos ,Sir; I viwed that answer but Idid not understant how $P$ sends $Bu$ to $u$

Comment: The you should post a comment on the answer that you do not understand asking for help.

Comment: Yes!I apologies sir, I shall comment in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the idempotent matrices $\{P_k\}_{ij}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jk}$ with one diagonal entry $1$ and all other entries zero. That $A$ commutes with $P_k$ implies that the $k$-th row and column of $A$ are zero except for the diagonal entry. Thus $A$ is diagonal. Now take the idempotent matrices with one diagonal block of the form

$$
\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$

and zeroes everywhere else. That $A$ commutes with these matrices implies that its diagonal entries are pairwise equal. Hence they are all equal, and thus $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: I think the idempotent matrix should have diagonal block $\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Babai: You're right, thanks, I've corrected the answer.